# Must declare the table variable error while creating a TVP function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-variable

I have the following function created with a TVP. I am inserting data initially into the TVP and then selecting from it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].employees_data(
  @employeeIds NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

  CREATE TYPE employees_data
  AS TABLE (can_view_all BIT,role_id INT ,employee_id INT);

  DECLARE @EmployeeDataTVP AS employees_data;

  INSERT INTO @EmployeeDataTVP (can_view_all, role_id, employee_id)
  SELECT
      ur.role_id,
      ua.employee_id
      INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.user_account_id = ua.id
      WHERE ua.employee_id IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@employeeIds, ','));


   RETURN (SELECT
    (
      CASE
      WHEN ed.role_id = 1 THEN (
        SELECT
          cc.id,
          ISNULL(cc.standard_name, cc.localized_name) AS name,
          cc.client_cost_center_id AS cost_center_id
        FROM s eccs
        LEFT JOIN centers cc on eccs.center_id = cc.id
        WHERE eccs.employee_id = ed.employee_id
        FOR JSON PATH
      )
      ELSE NULL
    END
    ) AS managed_places,
    ed.employee_id
  FROM @EmployeeDataTVP ed
   )
END
```

But i get the `Must declare the table variable \"@EmployeeDataTVP\".` error when i execute the function. I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Where is the [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)? You _should_ be using one instead of a comma-delimited list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create type but table variable instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].employees_data(
  @employeeIds NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @EmployeeDataTVP TABLE (can_view_all BIT,role_id INT ,employee_id INT);


  INSERT INTO @EmployeeDataTVP (can_view_all, role_id, employee_id)
  SELECT
      ur.role_id,
      ua.employee_id
      INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.user_account_id = ua.id
      WHERE ua.employee_id IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@employeeIds, ','));


   RETURN (SELECT
    (
      CASE
      WHEN ed.role_id = 1 THEN (
        SELECT
          cc.id,
          ISNULL(cc.standard_name, cc.localized_name) AS name,
          cc.client_cost_center_id AS cost_center_id
        FROM s eccs
        LEFT JOIN centers cc on eccs.center_id = cc.id
        WHERE eccs.employee_id = ed.employee_id
        FOR JSON PATH
      )
      ELSE NULL
    END
    ) AS managed_places,
    ed.employee_id
  FROM @EmployeeDataTVP ed
   )
END
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But i get `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS` error i believe it is because of `(SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@employeeIds, ',')` statement. Is there anything i can do to remove the error?

Comment: Try to change it with `SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@employeeIds, ',')`

Comment: Why use a multi-line TVF? This looks like it could easily be an inline TVF, which would perform way better.

Comment: How would a inline tvf work. Is there any documentation for it?